# unescape() function dont work properly

Tags: javascript

In one site there is this code:

```
document.write(unescape('%41%54%50%20%2f%20%20%57%54%41%20%4d%6f%73%63%6f%77'));
```

And this generate

```
ATP /  WTA Moscow (Shvedova - Pavlyuchenkova)
```

But if run that code I only get `ATP /  WTA Moscow`

Any ideas why this is happening ?

**Edit://** Here is the site

http://www.frombar.tv/

check this match

ATP / WTA Moscow (Makarova - Cibulkova)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible for that string to produce that other line. Each *%XX* represents a single letter. The unescape can not magically make up characters that are not in that string.

With the edit. View the page source you will see that the text in the () is not in the unescape call

```
<script language='Javascript'>document.write(unescape('%41%54%50%20%2f%20%20%57%54%41%20%4d%6f%73%63%6f%77'));</script> (Kuznetsov - Berlocq)</a></td>
```

Comment: The link proves what I said, just added an example above.

Answer (score 1):

There are 18 encoded characters in the string you provide.

`ATP /  WTA Moscow` is 18 characters long.

Whatever generates `(Shvedova - Pavlyuchenkova)`, it isn't the code you provided.

That said, `unescape` is broken for non-ASCII characters and so is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FFunctions#escape_and_unescape_functions)

> Here is the site…

The text in brackets appears after the script element as regular HTML.

Comment: @fufu — And as I said, that part of the HTML isn't generated by the script. It just appears in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

> (Shvedova - Pavlyuchenkova)

is being added after that code.

> %41%54%50%20%2f%20%20%57%54%41%20%4d%6f%73%63%6f%77

only represents "ATP / WTA Moscow"

Each 3 characters in the escaped string represents 1 readable character.

% = escape and [0-9a-f] = hex representation of a character

%20 = character 32 = " " [space]

%41 = character 65 = "A"

Answer (score 0):

```
str = Array.prototype.map.call('ATP /  WTA Moscow (Shvedova - Pavlyuchenkova)', function(x){return '%'+x.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);}).join('');

str === '%41%54%50%20%2f%20%20%57%54%41%20%4d%6f%73%63%6f%77%20%28%53%68%76%65%64%6f%76%61%20%2d%20%50%61%76%6c%79%75%63%68%65%6e%6b%6f%76%61%29';

str !== '%41%54%50%20%2f%20%20%57%54%41%20%4d%6f%73%63%6f%77';
```